# How to wait for createReadStream to finish?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I am confused because I cannot seem to **extract a value from an asynchronous operation**. Basically I have to parse a csv file and the operation is asynchronous as shown below.

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const results = [];
fs.createReadStream('courses.csv')
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
            .on('end', () => {
                console.log(results);
            });
```

---

I am unable to completly extract and isolate the results variable from that stream. I have tried doing this by wrapping it with a promise but it shows **pending**. Here is what I am doing.

```
const getData = () => {
    const prom = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        fs.createReadStream('courses.csv')
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
            .on('end', () => {
                res(results);
            });
    })
    return prom;
}

async function GIVEMEMYVALUE() {
    var result = await getData();
    return result;
};

let data = GIVEMEMYVALUE();
console.log(data);
```

---

I have read other questions relating to promises but I still don't see what I am doing wrong. I can do whatever I want with the results variable inside the 'end' callback but cannot seem to extract it(for whatever reason I want to extract it.)

1. Is it wrong to want to extract that value outside the scope of the 'end' callback ?
2. Can everything I possibly want to do with the results be done inside the callback ?

---

I have already gone through [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) but don't quite get it as it doesn't mention anything about pending promises.

Comment: GIVEMEMYVALUE returns a promise, if you do `GIVEMEMYVALUE().then(data => console.log(data))`, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

`GIVEMEMYVALUE` returns also an promise. However you could shorten your processes alot:

```
const getData = () =>
  new Promise((res, rej) => {
    fs.createReadStream("courses.csv")
      .pipe(csv())
      .on("data", data => results.push(data))
      .on("end", () => {
        res(results);
      });
  });

getData().then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

`async/ await` does not make your code work synchronous. As soon as you put `async` infront of your function, your function automatically returns an promise and acts like an promise.

Comment: I know that I can get data from the promise, how do i actually RETURN the data.

Comment: @HarshaLimaye you cannot!!

Comment: I do not want to log the data i want to return it to the highest/outermost scope.

Comment: Yeah thought so

Comment: So the answer to
 Is it wrong to want to extract that value outside the scope of the 'end' callback ? YES
Can everything I possibly want to do with the results be done inside the callback ? NO

Comment: @HarshaLimaye could you show us what you want to achieve with it?

Comment: @HarshaLimaye yes. you can put everything inside the callback.

Comment: Yeah basically I have a few csv files and I want to perform operations on them depending on the results. For example I am going to use that result as a filter in some other csv file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225622/discussion-between-harsha-limaye-and-ifaruki).